# NAIA to PNR Nichols?

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, philippines

The train from Nichols (https://goo.gl/maps/ncob95zjFuDALeNj7) goes directly to my destination (http://www.pnr.gov.ph/fares-tickets-nichols-station). I arrive at NAIA T3.

How do I go the 2 km from NAIA T3 to Nichols?

Walking is not an option due to luggage.

Comment: Wait until Line 9 is built and then you can take that. But that will probably be around 2025. Strangely, Google says the best option is walking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no train yet. I would use Grab. You can pre-install the app on your phone and just buy a local SIM card at the airport just outside the arrival gate but still inside the building.

If waiting is not a problem for you, there was a Grab booth in Terminal 3 last May 2019 when I last visited. ([Grab Booths](https://www.grab.com/ph/press/consumers-drivers/naia-now-open-grabcar/)).

When I was there the line was very long, and I didn't want to wait so I walked across to the other side and booked my ride from there. There is an elevator that you can use to access a [footbridge](https://goo.gl/maps/izH2c5j6h4iEygaG6) to the other side, and then book your Grab ride from outside McDonald's.

Comment: What is grab? Something like Uber? Are there taxis?

Comment: @Willeke Southeast Asia's biggest rideshare app, they actually bought up Uber's local operation. https://www.grab.com/

Comment: The footbridge was new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I took the foot bridge, flagged down a taxi. Price to Nichols was the same as Grab.

The train ride was free because they were testing a new train set (nice), but it was not on time - even by Filipino standard: 100 minutes delayed. It may have been due to flooding, but I will be reluctant to use the train when going to NAIA.